# get data-attributes with jQuery containing &quot;

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

When getting data-Attributes using jQuery's [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and this data-attribute contains the HTML-Entitys for double quotes, it fails to convert it to a JSON-Object. As you see below, it's simply seen as no valid JSON and therefore treats it like a string:

```js
var dataAsString = $("[data-someprop]").data("someprop");
var dataAsString2 = $("[data-someprop2]").data("someprop2");

var dataAsJSON = $("[data-anotherprop]").data("anotherprop");

$(".target1").append(typeof(dataAsString));
$(".target2").append(typeof(dataAsString2));
$(".target3").append(typeof(dataAsJSON));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-someprop='{
                    "key": "some &quot;value&quot; in quotes"
                    }'></div>

<div data-someprop2='{ "key": "some &quot;value&quot; in quotes" }'></div>

<div data-anotherprop='{
                    "key": "some value without quotes"
                    }'></div>



<div class="target1"></div>
<div class="target2"></div>
<div class="target3"></div>
```

How may i pass double quotes through JSON-Objects in data-attributes?

edit: Added a 3rd example to show, that it's not the line-breaks.

Comment: Did `JSON.parse` fail ?

Comment: The JSON-parsing is triggered/done by jQuery, if it detects it as a parseable JSON. This doesn't seem to be the case, as JSON.parse(jQuery('[data-someprop').attr('data-someprop')) fails as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be caused by the line-breaks in the HTML Encoded JSON string version. The below works fine:

```js
var dataAsString = $("[data-someprop]").data("someprop");
var dataAsString2 = $("[data-someprop2]").data("someprop2");
var dataAsString3 = $("[data-someprop3]").data("someprop3");
var dataAsString4 = $("[data-someprop4]").data("someprop4");

$(".target1").append(typeof(dataAsString) + ' - ' + dataAsString.key);
$(".target2").append(typeof(dataAsString2) + ' - ' + dataAsString2.key);
$(".target3").append(typeof(dataAsString3) + ' - ' + dataAsString3.key);
$(".target4").append(typeof(dataAsString4) + ' - ' + dataAsString4.key);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-someprop='{&quot;key&quot;: &quot;some value without quotes&quot;}'></div>
<div data-someprop2='{ "key": "some &quot;value&quot; in quotes" }'></div>
<div data-someprop3='{ "key": "some &nbsp;value&nbsp; in quotes" }'></div>
<div data-someprop4='{ 
    "key": "some &nbsp;value&nbsp; in quotes" 
}'></div>


<div class="target1"></div>
<div class="target2"></div>
<div class="target3"></div>
<div class="target4"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the problem. When only removing the line breaks, it still doesn't work. Your example (where you replaced " with &quot;) only shows, that &quot; is treated like ", even though they are not.

Comment: Added a 3rd example showing, that it's not the line-breaks, just to make it clear.

Comment: I updated the examples in my answer. The issue seems to be to do with only the `&quot;` HTML entity, and its position within the string which leads me to assume it's an issue with how jQuery deserialises the value before storing it in the object in cache. `&nbsp;` works fine in any position

Comment: Yes, `&quot;` is somehow treated like a normal double quote `"`, therefore closes the opening `"` and is therefore unable to be parsed as JSON correctly.